# Ability to access a Text Area from a different class

Tags: java, swing, class, function

How would i be able to run this function from my main() to build the gui, and then use code from elsewhere to handle the button click and retrieve input from the text field?

```
package main;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Gui {

public static void mainGUI() {
    UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
    java.net.URL imgApp = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("res/app.png");
    JFrame mainWin = new JFrame("jIRC");
    mainWin.setSize(1024, 720);
    mainWin.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainWin.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(imgApp).getImage());

    Container panel = mainWin.getContentPane();
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JTextArea inputBox = new JTextArea();
    inputBox.setSize(300, 100);
    inputBox.setLocation(500, 250);

    JButton sendButton = new JButton();
    sendButton.setText("Send");
    sendButton.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.ITALIC, 16));
    sendButton.setSize(72, 32);
    sendButton.setLocation(500, 500);

    panel.add(inputBox);
    panel.add(sendButton);
    mainWin.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Here's my class with the main function:

```
public class Run{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    main.Debug.startupDebug();
    main.Gui.mainGUI();
}
}
```

How would I go about placing some of my code in a non-static field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got everything in a static method, and that won't allow you to use any of the power of object-oriented programming. Consider creating OOP-compliant classes non-static fields and methods and with public getter and setter methods, and this way other classes can affect the behavior of this class.

**Edit**
You posted:

```
public class Run{ 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    main.Debug.startupDebug(); 
    main.Gui.mainGUI(); 
  } 
}
```

But what you need to do instead is something like:

```
public class Run{ 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    GUI gui = new GUI();
    Debug debug = new Debug();

     debug.setGui(gui);
     gui.setDebug(debug);

     gui.startGui();
  } 
}
```

Or something similar. Again avoid using static anything.

Comment: @DrZarreh: please post this code as an edit to your question since code does not format well in comments.

Comment: @DrZarreh: if you want to leverage Java to its fullest, yes, you will not regret this.

Comment: @DrZarreh: if you want to see a bigger example of having separate classes handle the GUI or view portion vs the listener or control section, please have a look at my answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728619/using-a-jfilechooser-with-swing-gui-classes-and-listeners/15729267#15729267).

Comment: I'm taking a look at it now, and im cleaning up my code abit.