# Best way to add ActionListeners to the View

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jbutton, actionlistener

After reading some posts, I am not sure about the difference between these two ways to implement ActionListeners. Is there any **good reason** to code in one way or another? What about view-decoupling?

***OPTION 1:***

Implement getButton()/setButton() methods in the view, and use these methods to add ActionListeners in the controller.

VIEW

```
public JButton getBtnRun() {
        return btnRun;
    }
```

CONTROLLER

```
m_view.getBtnRun().addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
```

***OPTION 2:***

Implement methods in the view, and call these methods from the controller, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15729267/2373397)

VIEW

```
public void setOpenFileAction(Action action) {
      displayText.setOpenFileButtonAction(action);
      fileMenu.add(new JMenuItem(action));
   }
```

CONTROLLER

```
view.setOpenFileAction(new OpenFileAction(view, model, "Open File",
            KeyEvent.VK_O));
```

Answer (score 3):

- IMHO It's better to have just one [Swing Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).
- If you e.g. enable/disable `Swing Action` it should enable/disable the `JMenu` and `JButton` as well.